# Can I create an HTML list in a D3.js SVG container

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is the code I am working on. I want to plot events for a certain year as an unordered list.

Is it possible to do using d3.js?

Code-

```
var mevent = svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", "year mevent")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("y", height - 450)
        .attr("x", width - 300)
        .attr("width", 1000)
        .attr("height", 200)
        .text("");


  // Updates the display to show the specified year.
  function displayYear(year) {
    dot.data(interpolateData(year), key).call(position).sort(order);
    year = Math.round(year);
    label.text(year);
    price.text("$ " + iacprices[year]);
    mevents_text = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < (mevents[year]).length; i++) {
        mevents_text = "*" + mevents_text 
        + (mevents[year])[i];
    }
    mevent.text(mevents_text);
```

Comment: That is certainly possible with D3. What specifically are you having problems with? I have no idea what your code does as half of it seems to be missing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can place HTML elements in a SVG with a [foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject).

[Example w/ d3](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1424037)